# Rails instance variable based on time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quick question. If I have a Model, say Charities, that has a `start_date` and an `end_date` attribute, how can I set that to be the `current_charity` from a method in the Controller?

I know I'll have to do some kind of `Charities.find(params[:something])`, and will just have to set that `current_charity` equal to one that's `start_date` is >= the current date, and who's `end_date` is <= the current date (there is only one "current" one at a time). I've usually just found a Model by the params[:id], so this is new to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a scope method in your model:

```
def self.current
  now = Time.now
  where("start_date <= ? AND ? <= end_date", now, now).first
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
current_charity = Charity.current
```

Comment: I like Thilo's answer better than mine. But make sure to write a lot of unit tests! Time-based logic is tricky and it's easy to miss an edge case. You can test time with a "mock clock" -- in RSpec, you do something like `Time.stub!(:now).and_return { Time.parse("2010-01-01 12:00") }` to trick your code into thinking it's a different day.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: search for the charity whose `end_date` is nil.

Longer answer: Your data model may not match your desired semantics. It seems to me that `start_date` is irrelevant here -- isn't the current charity the one whose end_date hasn't happened yet?

In general, one way to get the most recent X is to fetch all X's, sorted by descending date, and take the first one (or in SQL terms, use LIMIT 1). In ActiveRecord, it's something like this:

```
Charity.order("end_date DESC").first
```

though I'm a bit rusty on my Rails 3 AR syntax, and I don't think that query will solve your actual problem (though it does look kind of cool, amirite?).

Another solution is to denormalize -- add a `current` boolean field, and a `before_save` filter that sets `self[:current]` based on the logic you described. EDIT: Actually, that won't work here, since time marches on, and what is current will change outside the scope of an individual model's data.

My best advice is to write a lot of unit tests! Time-based logic is very tricky and it's easy to miss an edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add indexes in your database for columns that you will often be using in searches.

Add indexes by adding a db migration.